# How do i display the selected item from search box to a view page in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

The autosearch jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#somevalue").autocomplete({
        source:'@Url.Action("GetStudents","Search")',
        minLength: 2
    });
})

<input type="text" id="somevalue" name="somevalue" />
```

Now I want to display the selected item from the autosearch list to a view page of
Controller Action

here is the controller :

```
public ActionResult Details(int id) {
    // Retrieving each products by id
    var product = storeDB.Products.Find(id);
    return View(product);
}
```

Comment: GetStudents should return a JsonResult with an array of the students. The Details actionresult is really not much use.

Comment: Have a look at : http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json-in-mvc.html for a simple example

Comment: Ok, thanks . And i want to store the selected string value with id '#somevalue' to store in a local variable, so that with the string value i can filter the display list..Please provide some suggestion.am new to jquery.Thanks